# Problem with dictionary under iteration in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically this program is about to find all the `neighbours` of each node basing on `seqs`. Seqs means the directivity of each node. For example, `[1, 2]` means 1 points to 2. I use dictionary to store the nodes as keys and their `neighbours` as values.

```
seqs = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
nodes = {}
neighbors = set()
for i in range(len(seqs)):
    for j in range(len(seqs[i]) - 1, 0, -1):
        neighbors.add(seqs[i][j - 1])
        nodes[seqs[i][j]] = neighbors
        print(nodes)
```

The result of nodes should be `{2: {1}, 3: {1, 2}}`, but it turned out to be `{2: {1, 2}, 3: {1, 2}}`. In the last iteration, only the value to 3 should be updated, but both values get updated. I was confused by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question, that wasn't apparent to me when I first read it. Your logic is right, but alas! You have defined `neighbors` outside the loop and you are assigning the name `neighbors` to the set and then setting `nodes[2] = neighbors`. The point to note here is, `neighbors` here is just a name for the set, and `nodes[2]` gets the same set. So, in the subsequent iterations when you are modifying `neighbors` for `nodes[3]` the values of the set (`neighbors`) gets changed, and so does `nodes[2]`. What you need is `copy()`, so that you pass a copy of the set to `nodes[2]` instead of the actual set:

```
nodes = {}
neighbors = set()
for i in range(len(seqs)):
    for j in range(len(seqs[i]) - 1, 0, -1):
        neighbors.add(seqs[i][j - 1])
        nodes[seqs[i][j]] = neighbors.copy()
        print(nodes)
```

Output:

```
{2: {1}}
{2: {1}, 3: {1}}
{2: {1}, 3: {1, 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seqs = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
nodes = {}
for node in seqs:
    if node[1] in nodes:
        nodes[node[1]].add(node[0])
    else:
        nodes[node[1]] = set()
        nodes[node[1]].add(node[0])
print(nodes)
```

Try this hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below:

```
seqs = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
nodes = {}
neighbors = set()
for i in seqs:
    if i[1] not in nodes:
        nodes[i[1]] = set()
    nodes[i[1]].add(i[0])
print nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason both are updated is based on the following assignment:
**nodes[seqs[i][j]]=neighbors.**

When you add an item to the set in this statement "neighbors.add(seqs[i][j - 1])"
the value of neighbors is updated and both node[2] and node[3] are referenced to this variable.

Here is a solution code to your problem:

```
seqs = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
nodes = {}

for destination in set([seq[1] for seq in seqs]):
    nodes[destination] = set()
for [source, destination] in seqs:
    nodes[destination].add(source)
print(nodes)
```